# Regular expression for add_rewrite_rules with at least one hyphen

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, expression

I'm working with a regular expression for Wordpress' add_rewrite_rules.

My goal is to match URLs that have a single directory with at least one dash in there and return that directory.

I was able to find this:

`'^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){1,20}/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=location&location=$matches[1]'`

This matches if there is a hyphen, but returns only the end of the string (the part after the last hyphen).

So:

`test/`        fails (as it should, since there's no hyphen)

`te-st/`       passes, but only returns "st" for the variable.

`te-st-ing/`   passes, but only returns "ing" for the variable.

`te-st-ing/a/` fails (as there's another directory)

I'm a bit lost with expressions, but the goal is that "te-st" would pass but would return with the whole "te-st" string.  I think that should be an easy fix for someone who knows how to deal with expressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to ensure at least one hyphen is there you can use:

```
'^([^-/]*-[^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=location&location=$matches[1]'
```

Comment: That seems very close to working, but it is still matching something with additional directories (like `te-st-ing/test`) and returning the entire string as the variable value (in that example, `te-st-ing/test` is also the value returned, not `te-st-ing` as would be expected).

Comment: Even closer!  The value returned is correct now, but it is still matching the string even if there are additional directories - so `te-st-ing/test` returns as `te-st-ing` instead of returning false like it should.  `te-st-ing/`, however, is returning correctly with a value of `te-st-ing/`

Comment: ok I didn't realize you want `false` to be returned for `te-st-ing/test`. Try another update.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you so much, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this pattern:

```
^((?:\w+-){1,20}\w*)/?$
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/eU4jV8/5)